# How to assert on a map value object member?

Tags: java, assertj

Given are a map like this:

```
Map<String, BestClass> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

and a class BestClass like this:

```
class BestClass{
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

Now, this map is being populated during the program process.

Is there a clean way, **not including looping over the map keys**, to assert that, for example, none of the **b values** of the map object values are 0?

Comment: `assertThat(myMap).noneSatisfy((s, bestClass) -> assertThat(bestClass.b).isEqualTo(0));` see if this is clean to you.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way.
If you have any better - please suggest.

assertThat(myMap.values()).extracting(BestClass::getB).doesNotContain(0);

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
assertThat(list)
    .extracting("BestClass")
    .contains(entry("foo1", "bar1"), entry("foo2", "bar2"));
```

Comment: Thank you Konstantinos. I know this method. But I'd like to assert only on one of the object members. For example, in you example, only the bar values.